# Using the 'Project from view' option for unwrapping?

Tags: uv, image

I have ready eyes (a mirrored pair of eyeballs) with an annular section coloured by a material. I want the annulus to serve as the iris. So I got a jpg image of the iris from an eye photo and want this to be applied to the annulus.
I opened a UV window and imported this iris image.  I next selected the annulus in Edit mode in the 3D window picked the 'Project from view option' and in the material panel, I opened this image as a texture.
 But the image does not appear on the mesh.

Comment: Did you select UV as the mapping?

Comment: Yes, I am working in Cycles and UV is the default mapping anyway

Comment: Is the image not appearing in the viewport, the render, or neither?

Comment: @Eddie Could you share your node setup?

Comment: Mr Horns, thanks for asking for rendered view (in viewport) but the image covers the whole eye - except the annular par where I wanted it.

Comment: How does one send the node set up in this forum? (I know how it is done in Blender Artists).

Comment: @Eddie Welcome to the site :) Just edit your question with a screenshot. See [the help pages for instructions](http://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images).